# Is it possible to dynamically change maximum java heap size?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I know you can set max heap size at startup using -Xmx but is it possible to change it dynamically during runtime?

Is there any tool or (undocumented) api which will allow me to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Comment: Which is too bad so we could have GC ergonomic agents.

Answer (score 2):

Once the memory structure is fixed it cant be changed