# It is failed to create Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, jnlp

I got "failed to create JVM" error when I tried to run a jnlp file.

But it works when I removed the `max-heap-size="1100m"` from Java/j2se tag in jnlp.

It seems something wrong with the `max-heap-size`. I did some experiments to change the heap size in `eclipse.ini` file. The biggest heap size I could set is "940M", otherwise I got "Could not create JVM..." error when start the eclipse.

I suspect this is a memory(hardware) problem on my PC. My laptop is pretty new. But for some reason, my admin change the OS from Windows 7 to Windows XP. They now want to change back to windows 7.

I am using JDK 1.6 update 29 and eclipse Version: 3.7.0 Build id: I20110613-1736. Windows xp sp3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java webstart max-heap-size causes JVM cannot be started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285915/java-webstart-max-heap-size-causes-jvm-cannot-be-started)

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp

Comment: I can tell you it's not a memory/hardware problem because it happens on ALL Eclipses on any Windows I've seen so far...

Comment: I would guess a simple search on SO would give you a lot of info.
[Maximum memory Windows XP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171205/java-maximum-memory-on-windows-xp) for example

Answer (score 3):

Java requires continuous memory for the heap space.  Windows in particular tends to have a limited continuous region of memory available (which is smaller if other programs are running)

I would have thought you can have 1.2 GB heap, but this is far less than the 4 GB a 32-bit application can use in theory.

Switching to a 64-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS is the solution.  This will allow you to create a heap space close to the physical memory size.