# Error to launch jnlp file: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine and A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start, jnlp

OS: Windows 7 32-bit, Java: Java 7

1. I have downloaded a jnlp file
2. Double click on downloaded JNLP to run

jnlp file was not executed. The following error was shown at pop up:

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

I also tried to execute from command prompt as follows:

1. Execute the batch file containing the following command:
   echo "Running Content Studio on Java 7"............
   javaws -uninstall
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\javaws.exe" http://cbazyx.com/studio/Test.jnlp

But unfortunately same error occurred: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: Don't forget to add the java tag to Java questions. It has 48,200 followers, as opposed to the 82 for Java-7.

Comment: Your machine probably does not have enough memory based on your jnlp heap settings (it is very unlikely to get 2 GB on win 32 bits).

Comment: So, there is no possibility of happening this error on Windows 64 bit. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it as follows:

Open downloaded Studio.jnlp on an editor. I found the following line in my Studio.jnlp:

```xml
<j2se version="1.7.0_13+" 
  java-vm-args="-Xms128m -Xmx2048m" 
  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```

Where max-heap-size is not defined.

I defined initial-heap-size and max-heap-size as below:

```xml
<j2se version="1.7.0_13+" 
  initial-heap-size="100m" 
  max-heap-size="512m" 
  java-vm-args="-Xms128m -Xmx2048m" 
  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```

Finally, Save and double click on Studio.jnlp

It was successfully executed.

Comment: Related link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285915/java-webstart-max-heap-size-causes-jvm-cannot-be-started

Comment: The 2nd element is illogical.  It sets an initial heap size of both 128 Meg and 100 Meg, and a maximum size of both 512 Meg and 2048 Meg.  I'd guess the JRE that is running it is ignoring the `java-vm-args` and using the other two (which is why it now works), but the entire `java-vm-args` should be removed.  Also, be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  It would not have spotted that error, but will identify many others that are common in JNLP files.